# Do I need a ssl certificate if just pointing my domain to Cloudfront?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website running on a domain (e.g site.com). I have an additional domain(e.g sitecdn.com) which basically points to Amazon Cloudfront for delivery. Amazon Cloudfront in turn basically fetches the data from the main domain (site.com). I use this setup primarily to have multiple subdomains of my sitecdn.com to point to assets via the cdn.

The main website has a ssl certificate, and I intend to put all assets served from the cdn as https links only. Something like

```
<img src="https://img.sitecdn.com/image.jpg" />
```

I'm a little confused whether I need a ssl for my cdn domain. In cloudfront I can set the setting to allow both https and http traffic.

Do I need a ssl certificate for this ? If yes, then where do I install the ssl certificate, since I don't have a server for sitecdn.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do, and you'll need it on the `img.sitecdn.com` server.  Anywhere you want to use an HTTPS URL, the server(s) responsible for serving that site will need a certificate; preferably, a properly-signed certificate.

If you use a self-signed certificate, most browsers will complain about elements loaded from `sitecdn.com` when loading the `https://site.com` page.

If you serve those elements under http, most browsers will complain about the mixed-security mode when loading the `https://site.com` page.

**Edit**: serving HTTPS content from a cloud of servers is quite an undertaking, and yes, afaik it would involve installing an HTTPS key/certificate pair on every server that might be called on to provide that service.  If I were you, I wouldn't bother to do that, but instead serve all the content from the `site.com` server.

Comment: thanks..but I don't have a server for sitecdn.com..I just point it to a cloudfront distribution. How could we include cloudfront in the mix then ? Statically host sitecdn.com (with the cert), and then point each subdomain to cloudfront ? Or totally get rid of the sitecdn.com domain, and run everything from the main site (& subdomains) ? Any simpler workaround to this ?

Comment: thanks @MadHatter ..better to server everything from one place only then..

Answer (score 0):

With HTTPS, [Amazon CloudFront only supports using the `cloudfront.net` hostname assigned to you](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#CNAMEsAndHTTPS). So you won't be able to use your own domain name anyway; you'll have to use `https://whatever.cloudfront.net/resource.jpg` instead.

Comment: I'm talking about the case of CNAMES. I'm pointing a few subdomains to whatever.cloudfront.net

Comment: I know. You can't do it without getting certificate warnings. So see above.